# Writing program which prints out permutations

Tags: c, arrays, combinations, permutation

Consider a key access device with 5 buttons on it, and 2 numbers pertaining to each button:

Example:

Button A:             1              2

Button B:             3              4

Button C:             5              6

Button D:             7              8

Button E:             9              0

Each button has 2 possible choices; therefore, each 5-digit access code has 2^5 = 32 combinations.

For example:

code 1 3 5 7 9 would be entered using the same pattern of buttons as code 2 4 6 8 0 (pattern = ABCDE)

code 1 4 4 4 1 would be entered using the same pattern of buttons as code 1 3 3 3 2 (pattern = ABBBA)

After prompting the user for the access code and checking if it is within range (0 – 99999), compute and print to the screen the 32 different codes.

I was able to write this program, but it was done using 32 print statements shown in my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUM 5
#define COMBO 32

int main(){

    int input;
    int num[MAXNUM];
    int numtemp[MAXNUM];
    int i;

    printf("Please enter your 5 numbers within the range of [0~99999]:\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    while(input > 99999 || input < 0){
        printf("The inputted number is not in the specified range[0~99999], Please enter a new number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    }//end while

    for(i = 4; i >= 0; --i){
        num[i] = input%10;  
        input /= 10;
    }//set num array to each digit of inputted number

    for(i = 0; i < MAXNUM; ++i){
        switch(num[i]){
            case 1:
              numtemp[i] = 2;
              break;
            case 2:
              numtemp[i] = 1;
              break;
            case 3:
              numtemp[i] = 4;
              break;
            case 4:
              numtemp[i] = 3;
              break;
            case 5:
              numtemp[i] = 6;
              break;
            case 6:
              numtemp[i] = 5;
              break;
            case 7:
              numtemp[i] = 8;
              break;
            case 8:
              numtemp[i] = 7;
              break;
            case 9:
              numtemp[i] = 0;
              break;
            case 0:
              numtemp[i] = 9;
              break;
        }//end switch
    }//array numtemp now has all opposite values of array num

    //32 print statements for the different combinations
    printf("Here are your 32 combinations:\n");
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], num[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], num[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], num[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], num[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], numtemp[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], numtemp[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], num[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], num[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], num[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], num[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], num[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], num[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], num[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], num[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], num[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], num[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], numtemp[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], numtemp[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], num[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], num[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], num[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], num[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], num[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], num[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], num[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", num[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", numtemp[0], numtemp[1], numtemp[2], numtemp[3], numtemp[4]);
}//end of main
```

`numtemp` contained all the opposite values of `num`, and printed the 32 combinations this way. I would like to know if anyone could come up with an easier solution. This was a lab assignment which I received full credit for, but I would like to improve the code so it doesn't have those 32 print statements. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In C++ it's [very easy to get permunations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: No, it's fine. They read 1 5 digit number then split it up into 5 1 digit numbers. But it fails if the number is not 5 digits. If the user inputs 43, then the array will contain { 0, 0, 0, 4, 3 }.

Comment: It reads one 5 digit number, and the for loop right after breaks the numbers up into an array which holds each of those 5 numbers. The code works, I just want to know a better way to improve it. This is also assuming the user inputs an actual 5 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all possible codes, then you can just use a binary representation of all numbers from 0 to 32 (use `std::bitset` for this), then display each corresponding bit, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string letter{"ABCDE"};
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << letter[j] << std::bitset<5>(i)[j] << " ";
        }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you use C, then replace `std::string` by `const char*` and write your own bit-transforming routine.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with that language, and I can't seem to follow your code. I thought about bit shifting, but have no idea how I could implement it using C, especially for a program like this.

Comment: @NicolasO you can implement a bit-display using the bit-shift operator `>>` and and-ing each extracted bit with `1`. Search for "binary representation of a number in C" and you'll see how it's done. If your question is C-only, please remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Sorry about the C++ tag, it was just a recommended tag. I'll check out the binary representation of numbers and see where I go from there. Thanks!